# Splitting the Rows of a MySQL Query Using Ruby and Writing to a CSV File

Tags: mysql, ruby, csv, split, row

Using Ruby to automate MySQL queries from a remote database, I wish to split rows based on the value of the `month` query found below.

This is to generate a week-by-week (Wednesday to the following Tueday) report for the month of June back in 2014 for all clients based off of the start date.  While nothing else in the report will change, the duplication of rows is based off of that start date (explained in the `case` statement below).

Note the use of the `mysql2`, `watir` and `csv` gems here.

Simplified code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "mysql2"
require "watir"
require "csv"

puts "Initializing Report"

Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)

mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "1.2.3.4", :username => "user", :pass => "password", :database => "db")

puts "Successfully accessed db"

month = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m') FROM db.table WHERE db.start.group = 1;")

day = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%d') FROM db.table WHERE db.start.group = 1;")

report = mysql.query("SELECT db.table.client, SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m/%d/%Y'), SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.end, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM db.table WHERE db.start.group = 1;")

case month
when 5
  # code splitting one row into four
when 6
  if day <= 4
    # code splitting one row into four using weekOf
  elsif day >= 11 and day <= 17
    # code splitting one row into three using weekOf
  elsif day >= 18 and day <= 24
    # code splitting one row into two using weekOf
  else
    # no splitting; only one row using weekOf
  end
end

CSV.open("Report.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Week of", "Client", "Start Date", "End Date"]
  weekOf.zip(report).each {|row| csv << row.flatten}
end

puts "Results can be found in Report.csv"
```

Current output (if I were to comment out that `case` statement, remove the `"Week of",` in the CSV header and only write the `report` query to the CSV):

```
Client, Start Date, End Date
companyrecordlabel, 05/20/2014, 07/09/2015
beeUrself, 05/27/2014, 02/01/2016
overflowStack, 06/04/2014, 12/11/2015
chapoChaps, 06/11/2014, 01/16/2016
Meds4U, 06/18/2014, NULL
  .
  .
  .
```

And I would desire the following output:

```
Week of, Client, Start Date, End Date
06/04/2014, companyrecordlabel, 05/20/2014, 07/09/2015
06/11/2014, companyrecordlabel, 05/20/2014, 07/09/2015
06/18/2014, companyrecordlabel, 05/20/2014, 07/09/2015
06/25/2014, companyrecordlabel, 05/20/2014, 07/09/2015
06/04/2014, beeUrself, 05/27/2014, 02/01/2016
06/11/2014, beeUrself, 05/27/2014, 02/01/2016
06/18/2014, beeUrself, 05/27/2014, 02/01/2016
06/25/2014, beeUrself, 05/27/2014, 02/01/2016
06/04/2014, overflowStack, 06/04/2014, 12/11/2015
06/11/2014, overflowStack, 06/04/2014, 12/11/2015
06/18/2014, overflowStack, 06/04/2014, 12/11/2015
06/25/2014, overflowStack, 06/04/2014, 12/11/2015
06/11/2014, chapoChaps, 06/11/2014, 01/16/2016
06/18/2014, chapoChaps, 06/11/2014, 01/16/2016
06/25/2014, chapoChaps, 06/11/2014, 01/16/2016
06/18/2014, Meds4U, 06/18/2014, NULL
06/25/2014, Meds4U, 06/18/2014, NULL
  .
  .
  .
```

For clarity: the `"Client"` as `companyrecordlabel` has four rows because its `"Start Date"` is in May while the `"Client"` `Meds4U` was only split into two rows because its `"Start Date"` was on the 18th of June.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I constructed the **FULL** code for the following answer based on several assumptions:

- No `DATE_FORMAT(db.table.end, '%m') = 6`
- You wish for all the
  companies listed to be in the order they are found in (i.e.
  `db.table.id`)
- Query time isn't a gigantic issue for you
- You wanted but couldn't or forgot to include an array named `weekOf`

You also seem to have the term `SELECT` too many times in your query.  And even for a query as small as the sample you provided you may want to separate it and avoid keeping it all on one line:

```
month = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m')
    FROM db.table
    WHERE db.start.group = 1;")
```

instead of:

`month = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m') FROM db.table WHERE db.start.group = 1;")`

And now for the code itself:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "mysql2"
require "watir"
require "csv"

puts "Initializing Report"

Mysql2::Client.default_query_options.merge!(:as => :array)

mysql = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "1.2.3.4", :username => "user", :pass => "password", :database => "db")

puts "Successfully accessed db"

date = mysql.query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m'),
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%d')
  FROM db.table
  WHERE db.start.group = 1;")

report = mysql.query("SELECT c, s, e FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT db.table.id
  db.table.client AS c,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m/%d/%Y') AS s,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.end, '%m/%d/%Y') AS e
  FROM db.table
  WHERE db.start.group = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT db.table.id
  db.table.client AS c,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m/%d/%Y') AS s,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.end, '%m/%d/%Y') AS e
  FROM db.table
  WHERE db.start.group = 1
  HAVING ((DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m') = 5) OR (DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%d') <= 4))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT db.table.id
  db.table.client AS c,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m/%d/%Y') AS s,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.end, '%m/%d/%Y') AS e
  FROM db.table
  WHERE db.start.group = 1
  HAVING ((DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m') = 5) OR (DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%d') <= 11))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT db.table.id
  db.table.client AS c,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m/%d/%Y') AS s,
  DATE_FORMAT(db.table.end, '%m/%d/%Y') AS e
  FROM db.table
  WHERE db.start.group = 1
  HAVING ((DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%m') = 5) OR (DATE_FORMAT(db.table.start, '%d') <= 18))) AS alias
  ORDER BY db.table.id) AS alias2;")

weekOf = []

date.each do |mon, day|
  if mon === 5
    weekOf << "06/04/2014"
    weekOf << "06/11/2014"
    weekOf << "06/18/2014"
    weekOf << "06/25/2014"
  elsif mon === 6
    if (day.to_i <= 4)
      weekOf << "06/04/2014"
      weekOf << "06/11/2014"
      weekOf << "06/18/2014"
      weekOf << "06/25/2014"
    elsif ((day.to_i >= 11) && (day.to_i <= 17))
      weekOf << "06/11/2014"
      weekOf << "06/18/2014"
      weekOf << "06/25/2014"
    elsif ((day.to_i >= 18) && (day.to_i <= 24))
      weekOf << "06/18/2014"
      weekOf << "06/25/2014"
    else
      weekOf << "06/25/2014"
    end
  else
    puts "Error: #{mon} is before May"
  end
end

CSV.open("Report.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["Week of", "Client", "Start Date", "End Date"]
  weekOf.zip(report).each {|row| csv << row.flatten}
end

puts "Results can be found in Report.csv"
```

The explanation:

I took the assumption that query time wasn't a big issue for you seeing that your sample query is rather small and contains no `JOIN`.  If you find that your query is becoming larger than ten or so `INNER JOIN` (for, say, tables with hundreds of thousands of entries each) then this might no longer be the best solution for you.

This solution has **two** parts.

The **first** is the duplication of rows from the database itself using `UNION ALL`.  This means repeating the entire query and adding criteria below to specify when this duplication happens.

That's where the `HAVING` clause comes in.  When using `UNION ALL`, `HAVING` must be used in this fashion instead of `WHERE`; as the latter will result in an error for MySQL.

Also be sure to keep in mind that every MySQL table created as a result of a subquery must have an alias: `alias` and `alias2`.  I used not one but two nested queries in order to `ORDER BY db.table.id` (going off one of my assumptions) and to then select only the columns we need for the next part.

Finally, I combined the two separate `month` and `day` and instead turned them into one `date`: which will return a two dimensional array when iterated over.

**Second**: I created that `weekOf` array that you probably meant to but forgot to include.

I then iterated over `date` in order to push the right `"06/#{day}/2014"` into the `weekOf` array.

And that's it!  I hope this helps.